# Problem in code while using Python msvcrt

Tags: python, python-3.x, msvcrt

Only getting a blank screen, what is wrong?

```
import msvcrt
while(1):
  choice = msvcrt.getch()
  if(choice =='a'):
      print('a')
  elif(choice =='s'):
      print('s')
```

Comment: I wanted to take single character input from the user without pressing enter

Comment: Your code looks fine to me?
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-standard-library/0596000960/ch12s11.html

Comment: Ah, this is not a shebang issue, is it?

Comment: @Aiyion.Prime Windows doesn't know about shebangs

Comment: @Aiyion.Prime The reference you provide is to a book about Python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `getch()` returns a byte not a string. If you press `a` the value of `choice` is the bytestring `b'a'` which is not the same as the string `'a'`. Consider this:

```
>>> choice = b'a'
>>> choice == 'a'
False
>>> choice.decode() == 'a'
True
```

And your screen is remaining blank because neither `if`-condition can ever be true, and you have no catch-all `else:` clause. You could have discovered this for yourself simply by printing out the value of `choice`.

Change your test from

```
if choice =='a':
```

to

```
if choice.decode() == 'a':
```

(and do drop those unnecessary parens from your `if` tests).

In Python 2, your original code would have worked the way you expect.